# Read a column from the table using disconnected data access and insert individual values to a text file.

Tags: c#, asp.net

So my web form consists of a DropDownList,  which on page load gets populated with item names from a table in my database. On clicking the button, I want the selected name to be inserted into a text file on my local folder.

Additionally, I want the selected name to have its first three letters capitalized, when it is written into the text file.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

So far, I've gotten the web form part done.

[Web Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vfUg.png)

Heres my .cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Market;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT item_name FROM sales_detail", con);
            SqlDataReader reader;
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(reader["item_name"].ToString());
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Market;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT item_name FROM sales_detail where item_name = @item_name", con);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_name", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
    }
}
```

Am I going right? Or is there a better way to do this.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "...inserted into a text file on my local folder" ? You can have the user download a file but you cannot write to a file on the client from the web server.

Comment: Simply put being able to read a cell from my table in my database, and writing its content into a text file. All of this is offline.

Comment: A web application is not the right choice, you cannot go offline with webforms using code-behind.